# Do you have a common term to express the cost of seeing a doctor in contrast with the medication cost?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Some medical insurances only cover these costs:

-the fee that allows you to be checked by a doctor.

-the doctor might do some procedure on you, for example, removing earwax from your ear. Then, the medical insurances also cover that fee.

-the doctor might do some tests and you have to pay fees for it. These fees are also covered.

But the medical insurances do not cover medication/ medicine fees.

**Do you have a common term to express the cost of seeing a doctor in contrast with the medication cost in everyday English?**

A chatbot suggests using "doctor's visit".

For example, *my medical insurance only covers the cost of the doctor's visit not the cost of the medication*

Comment: This sentence is good enough for discussing the matter with a member of the general public. If you're talking to your insurance, you should use their terms. Many insurances also distinguish between a "well visit," a regularly scheduled preventative checkup, and a "sick visit," seeing the doctor for a concern.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a doctor's visit refers to the consultation and possibly associated procedures with the doctor, differentiating it from medication which is typically purchased separately. You can also use "office visit" and "consultation fee", but your sentence is correct and understandable. "Doctor's visit" is a commonly used term.

Answer (score 1):

"Doctor visit" is good. Conceivably one could debate whether "doctor visit" includes services by other people done at the time you visited the doctor. Like I used to go to a doctor whose office staff included lab technicians who would take a blood or urine sample before you visited the doctor, run the tests while you were with the doctor, and then give the doctor the results during or shortly after the visit. Would you count the cost of this as part of a "doctor visit"? Debatable, I think.

I would say "doctor's fee" to mean the cost specifically of seeing the doctor.